# phpMyadmin Temporarily unavailable

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin, cpanel

I have a demo project hosted with freehosting dot com which I really need to transfer to another server. The problem is whenever I try to  access phpmyadmin I get a  "temporarily unavailable" error. Now I cannot access the database neither change the login details due to this error.

When I try to download through "Backup" function in the CPanel all I get is a potion of my database which is irrelevant:

```
mysqldump: Got error: 1146: Table 'creati83_creati.joe_commentmeta' doesn't exist when using LOCK TABLES
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 5.5.36, for Linux (x86_64)
--
-- Host: mysql1.freehosting.com    Database: creati83_creati
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.6.17-65.0-587.trusty

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

This is all I get yet the database it larger than this.

How can I access, transfer or export my DB without using phpmyadmin?

Comment: Is `creati83_creati` your database? Are you allowed to access your database externally using a mysql client on your pc?

Comment: yes. That is my database. I also have others iin the same host but I I can be able to recover one I'll be able to recover the rest. I am not sure of what you mean by externally. The only way I know how is through phpMyadmin in the Cpanel. Please if you can elaborate further

Comment: With externally i mean something like `mysql --host=mysql1.freehosting.com --user=` in your command line window (remote access). If there is some way to get access to your database (either with an remote client)  or with a simple php script, you could check what a `CHECK TABLE joe_commentmeta` returns.

Comment: Thanks a lot @t.niese. Could you please tell me on of those external clients if you don't mind. I am green in database recovery

Comment: That is nothing about recovery but basics about mysql itself: [mysql — The MySQL Command-Line Tool](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql.html). Anyway using the last backup you have is most of the time better then spending the time to recover from a corrupted database.